# How to remove previously created element before adding new set of elements

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="number"/>
<input type="button" value="create button" onclick="createbtn()"/> 
<br> 
<script>
function createbtn() 
{
 var n=document.getElementById("number").value;

 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "button");
  x.setAttribute("value", i);
  x.setAttribute("id","x"+i);
  document.body.appendChild(x);

 }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code takes the value from text field and creates number of buttons equal to the value entered in text field.Now if new value is entered in text I wanted to clear previously created button before creating new buttons.How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Just create an element, i.e. a `div` and clear it before adding new elements. Something like:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<input type="text" id="number"/>
<input type="button" value="create button" onclick="createbtn()"/> 
<br> 
<script>
    function createbtn(){
        var n=document.getElementById("number").value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
            x.setAttribute("type", "button");
            x.setAttribute("value", i);
            x.setAttribute("id","x"+i);
            document.getElementById("result").appendChild(x);
        }

     }
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/acor/729mwe7p/)

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class name to the newly-creating elements.

```
 x.setAttribute("class", "some-class-name");
```

Then remove all elements byClass, before adding the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button container element and add all buttons to that container. Clear the contents before you add new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Create a container in which to put the buttons. At the start of your function, clear the container.

```html
<input type="text" id="number"/>
<input type="button" value="create button" onclick="createbtn()"/> 
<div class="buttons"></div>

<script>
function createbtn() 
{
 var buttons_container = document.getElementsByClassName("buttons")[0];
 var n=document.getElementById("number").value;

 buttons_container.innerHTML = '';

 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "button");
  x.setAttribute("value", i);
  x.setAttribute("id","x"+i);
  buttons_container.appendChild(x);

 }
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c3j1ebre/